# Time series digitization

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining, pattern-recognition

I am looking for a viable method to create an alphabet out of multidimensional time series data. My intention is to use pattern/string matching algorithms (potentially genetic) to find profitable patterns.

Extra points if I can do this in R.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide an example explaining what you mean.

Comment: I remember some time series segmentation method do what you're looking for. I just dont remember the name at all.

Comment: You probably mean digitization, discretization traditionally means going from continuous time to discrete time, and digitization means going from real values to a finite alphabet.

Comment: Yeah, looks like digitization is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a way to digitize your data so that two vectors that are close by are more likely to end up receiving the same letter in the alphabet.

A simple solution is to cluster your data (e.g., kmeans() in R) and assign to each vector the identity of the cluster it ends up in.